# ASP.NET WebServices authorisation

Tags: asp.net, web-services, authorization

I have an ASP.NET web service that is accessed by some software application. In my "Login" method I create a FormsAuthenticationTicket, encrypt it, and return to web service user. This ticket is expected to be sent to each of web service methods: GetLicense, CreateProduct, etc.
When ticket is received, it is decrypted and checked if expired.

The problem is "Logout" method: there are no any ability to force ticket expiration. If it is created with 60 minutes length, it can be marked as expired. Nevertheless user called "Logout" method, he still will be able to use the same ticket later.

Please advise, what is a best practice to do authorization for web service users?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. Any thoughts are welcome. Probably I need to use another mechanism (not a FormsAuthenticationTicket object).

Comment: How are you evaluating if the ticket is expired?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772648/formsauthentication-signout-on-server/2774379#2774379

Comment: It has 'IsExpired' property and Expiration period is defined by parameters required by object constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What I see as easy solution is to put ticket into HttpContext.Current.Application collection with

```
HttpContext.Current.Application.Add(ticket)
```

When user is trying to use ticket - check if it is in collection. If yes - check if it is expired...

When user call 'Logout' method - I will just remove ticket from collection...

Seems like a quick workaround to force FormsAuthenticationTicket expiration.

Please let me know if you see any lack of this approach.

Thanks.